Implementing Background Colors in Bootstrap vertical tabs and forms
In working on a project recently, I have noticed that I am limited to backgrounds solely outlined in bootstrap files and sites. I want it to match the existing color of the background according to my CSS and HTML styling. I have noticed that those items that I have utilized bootstrap to create are the only areas of the page in white. Any ideas on how to get the background to be similar (if not close enough) to the background so that it is not standing out so much?
added style inline within the boot strap element such as   along with the class for items like the verticle tabs which remained white and didn't allow the page background to change.
css coding for turning the background color to blue
page run of site where now the css background know longer works and is not allowing for color to be added to verticle menu (styling removed from html for verticle menu)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors; provide a proper [mre] of the issue instead.
